# Using <Content> tag with pageKey does not work in VuePress 1.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

During development, we created a component that went through each `index.md` file in a folder based on the `this.$site.pages.path` list.  After upgrading to 1.0.0-alpha.39 to fix a few other issues we were having, It no longer works.

Component code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Content v-for="page in changelogPages" :key="page.key" :pageKey="page.key"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash"
export default {
  computed: {
    changelogPages: function () {
      let pages = this.$site.pages
        .filter(pages => pages.path.startsWith("/docs/change-log/2"))

      return _.orderBy(pages, 'path').reverse()
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {}
  }
}

</script>
```

This results in the following errors.
[image]

looking at the Vue plugin for chrome, I can see that the page.key is there.

[image]

In the page, I am simply calling `<ChangeLogList />` which invokes the above global-component.

AS AN FYI:  The VuePress ecosystem does not require me to register markdown files, so the typical answer of "did you register your component" is not correct.

Reference Links in repo

Global Component : https://github.com/okta/okta.github.io/blob/VuePress/packages/%40okta/vuepress-theme-default/global-components/ChangeLogList.vue

Component invoking ChangeLogList:https://github.com/okta/okta.github.io/blob/VuePress/packages/%40okta/vuepress-theme-default/components/ChangeLog.vue

Page that is uisng ChangeLog (View Raw): https://github.com/okta/okta.github.io/blob/VuePress/packages/%40okta/vuepress-site/docs/change-log/index.md

Logged in an issue at [Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/1173) as well, but no responses there

Comment: I've also tried this and believe it is broken.  It appears as if it can render the current `Content` component but not other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<Content v-for="page in changelogPages" :key="page.key" :page-key="page.key"/>
```